# Should abstract classes have implementation in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In Java, I'm use to seeing abstract classes without any implementation. I can't remember, but I don't think it's even possible to include implementation details. But in Kotlin, I have seen abstract classes contain implementation details. What I don't understand is that the Kotlin docs clearly state:

> An abstract member does not have an implementation in its class

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html

Can someone explain why the docs contradict the fact that you can implement details in an abstract class.

Comment: can you add a simple code example ?

Comment: No need for a code sample. Any class that has functions with implementation in those functions can be used as an abstract class. I think the documentation is incorrect.

Comment: Well, you should definitely add a simple code example, because your question is unclear, as to what you mean by "implement details in an abstract class", and what behavior you expect to not differ between Java and Kotlin abstract classes exactly.

Answer (score 6):

The quote applies only to `abstract` **members**. An `abstract` class may have non- `abstract` members. And these members must have an implementation:

```
abstract class AbstractClass {
    abstract val abstractVal: Int
    fun notAbstractFun(): String = "Implementation details"
}
```